# When to allocate memory to char *

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, constants

I am bit confused when to allocate memory to a char * and when to point it to a const string.

Yes, I understand that if I wish to modify the string, I need to allocate it memory.

But in cases when I don't wish to modify the string to which I point and just need to pass the value should I just do the below? What are the disadvantages in the below steps as compared to allocating memory with `malloc`?

```
char *str = NULL;

str = "This is a test";

str = "Now I am pointing here";
```

Comment: Those strings are allocated at compile time in the read-only part of the data section of the executable image. No need to allocate memory dynamically (during runtime) in this case.

Comment: You start using `-Wextra` and `-Wall` or else I shall find you, and I will kill you.

Comment: @barakmanos: How to 'allocate' something at compile time?

Comment: @Zaibis: You let the compiler do it for you.

Comment: @barakmanos: No the compiler isn't the one who allocates the memory. the compiler is just a translation unit. The compiler makes your code to be udnerstandable by the machine. But the one who is allocating something is in anycase the computing unit i.e. your CPU. All the compiler does is creating the binarys that are understandable by the unit that it knows it has to allocate something. If the compiler would allocate something would mean that the compiled binary file could contain RAM what is just paradoxic.

Comment: @Zaibis: That's just "playing around with words" (forgot the English terminology for that)!!! You could just as well say the same about runtime memory allocation. Of course, during runtime, the entire executable image is loaded into memory by the OS, and those strings reside at a relative address from the base address of the image (BTW, you could also claim here that it's the CPU that does the "physical" work). I said "compiler" as in the opposite of the programmer (implying that the programmer does not have to deal with allocating memory for these strings).

Comment: @barakmanos: Totally aggree to that. I jsut wanted to clarify that saying the compiler allocates something is just stated in the wrong layer. And of course all work is done by this unit after all. But for the concept we use to understand what is behind all this scences we divide processes in layers. and the layer where a compilation takes place the only thing that gets allocated is the memory the compiler needs for its own work. But a compiler never will allocate anything that will be available after the compilation is finished.I hope you aggree that this is in fact a slightly different thing.

Comment: @Zaibis: We use "layers encapsulation" in just about everything we describe, to ourselves or to others, in any field whatsoever. It's the only plausible way to go about if you want your conversation to make any sense.

Comment: @Zaibis "playing around with words"; Semantics?

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner: Is this really relevant? I guess its clear what I was mentioning.

Answer (score 21):

Let's try again your example with the `-Wwrite-strings` compiler warning flag, you will see a warning:

```
warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type
```

This is because the type of "This is a test" is `const char *`, not `char *`. So you are losing the constness information when you assign the literal address to the pointer.

For historical reasons, compilers will allow you to store string literals which are constants in non-const variables.

This is, however, a bad behavior and I suggest you to use `-Wwrite-strings` all the time.

If you want to prove it for yourself, try to modify the string:

```
char *str = "foo";
str[0] = 'a';
```

This program behavior is undefined but you may see a segmentation fault on many systems.
Running this example with [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/), you will see the following:

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x4005E4
```

The problem is that the binary generated by your compiler will store the string literals in a memory location [which is read-only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment). By trying to write in it you cause a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Writing_to_read-only_memory).

What is important to understand is that you are dealing here with two different systems:

1. The C typing system which is something to help you to write correct code and can be easily "muted" (by casting, etc.)
2. The Kernel memory page permissions which are here to protect your system and which shall always be honored.

Again, for historical reasons, this is a point where 1. and 2. do not agree. Or to be more clear, 1. is much more permissive than 2. (resulting in your program being killed by the kernel).

So don't be fooled by the compiler, the string literals you are declaring are really constant and you cannot do anything about it!

Considering your pointer `str` read and write is OK.
However, to write correct code, it should be a `const char *` and not a `char *`. With the following change, your example is a valid piece of C:

```
const char *str = "some string";
str = "some other string";
```

(`const char *` pointer to a const string)

In this case, the compiler does not emit any warning. What you write and what will be in memory once the code is executed will match.

Note: A const pointer to a const string being `const char *const`:

```
const char *const str = "foo";
```

The rule of thumb is: always be as constant as possible.

If you need to modify the string, use dynamic allocation (malloc() or better, some higher level string manipulation function such as strdup, etc. from the libc), if you don't need to, use a string literal.

Comment: I'm torn - you get a +1 for your Rule of Thumb, but nearly got a -1 for your suggestion to use malloc() - there are sooooooo many pitfalls of using the heap, that malloc() et al need to be used with serious caution!

Comment: Otherwise good answer, but I think the part about proving it is misleading. Writing to literals is undefined behaviour, and you don't necessarily get segfault on all systems. You can **never** trust testing in C, because UB is not guaranteed to work always incorrectly. You need to know that code is correct. And that is why enabling all compiler warnings is extremely important when working with C.

Comment: @Andrew Modified a bit the answer but if you do string manipulation in C you _have_ to pay attention to what you're doing anyway ;)

Comment: @user694733 Fixed the answer to say that this is undefined behavior. After all, loading string literals on a page with read-write permission would be deemed nowadays as a security flaw...

Comment: Usage of malloc() is banned from our process.

Comment: "some higher level string manipulation function such as strdup, etc. from the libc" `strdup` is not an ISO C function but a POSIX one.

Comment: First of all: const doesn't mean it WILL be in read only memory. it just MAY be. thats the wording of the standard. Also if you explain how a constant pointer to a constant value works I'm asuming you know the semantic of const so please write the logical and not the exceptional variant of const. So rather write `char const * const` as `const char * const`. As the standard says (this is just my own wording) the occurence of `const`describes the type to its left. if there isn't anything to its left it is related to the type to its right.

Comment: I understand that people who don't know the standard do this. But this is just confusing so I don't udnerstand how you can know that its just an exception and do it anyway.

Comment: @Andrew: What is wrong with using malloc? How the heck do you intend to write a C programm that uses more then 2MB Ram in 1 scope without using one of the std allocation functions?

Comment: @tehnyit: Same to you: How your process intents to have more than 2 MB of Ram in a single scope without increasing the stack size? (What is probabbly much riskier than just using malloc) there is some much wrong with all this comments here...

Comment: @Zaibis - Malloc() has all sorts of problems... and even worse, programmers do not seem to know how to use if safely!  For example, do you **always** check the return status for NULL, and *errno* for errors?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes ofcourse I do. Otherwise I will produce code that fails on run time. And if people don't check this, its not a problem of malloc it is a problem of programmers that are programming in a language they shouldn't. It is the same why so many people advise to not use goto's... Because there are many people that would use them to produce unreadable and erroneous code. But thats not a problem with goto and I for my self do not avoid using gotos. If I encounter a situation where it may improve stuff (what exists!) I would use it. Though so far I never encountered such situation, my self.

Comment: @Andrew: And just as side note: I even differ in output between stdout and stderr in my code. But Advising not using malloc is the wrong approach. Then it is better to advise not using C at all UNTILL you know all the site effects things may have in C. But avoiding allocation functions in C is simply unpracticable for productional code.

Comment: @Ziabis - While I agree with *a problem of programmers that are programming in a language they shouldn't* I disagree with you about malloc() - and many big companies (eg NASA, Boeing, BAE and most automotive companies agree with me that malloc() is too error prone to be safe in safety critical systems!

Comment: @Andrew: But what are the alternatives when you need to process data that is exceeding the amount that is provided by the stack?

Comment: @Andrew: Or are you really just refering to malloc and not to the allocation utility at all? so that calloc is allready fine? In that case I still don't know why it may be better to avoid it. But I have to say I never use malloc() aswell as it is so unpracticable to have to call memset to init it before using it. That I just user calloc() in my code.

Comment: @Zaibis - I am referring to the whole set of dynamic-allocation functions.

Comment: @Andrew: Ok this lets open my question, how you process datasets that are greate then the stacksize?

Comment: We're getting well away from the Answer here... perhaps we should move this to Chat?  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85390/misra-musings

Comment: @Ziabis, in this context, the phrase "using the right tool for the job" applies. In general, dynamic allocation of anything means more analysis is required as the overall system is not understood yet. I come from an automotive world and embedded. If we don't have a good a understanding how much memory is required, we don't start coding until we do. If more memory is needed during runtime, an error is created and logged but more memory allocation is not performed.

Comment: @tehnyit: I totally understand and aggree with that. As I allready discussed with Andrew in the chat, I dont see where the OP or the answers takes refference to the embedded's world, so was just reading that people advise to avoid that at all. But there are jobs which (even well planed) can't be done without them. i.e. whiles planing the development of a viedeogame you can't really get a clou of in which scene there will be how many vertice to render and prec to be stored. So I just saw some one advising to avoid something at all what isn't to avoid in every case. Got my point?

Answer (score 5):

If you know that `str` will always be read-only, why not declare it as such?

```
char const * str = NULL;
/* OR */
const char * str = NULL;
```

Well, actually there is one reason why this may be difficult - when you are passing the string to a read-only function that does not declare itself as such. Suppose you are using an external library that declares this function:

```
int countLettersInString(char c, char * str);
/* returns the number of times `c` occurs in `str`, or -1 if `str` is NULL. */
```

This function is well-documented and you know that it will not attempt to change the string `str` - but if you call it with a constant string, your compiler might give you a warning! You know there is nothing dangerous about it, but your compiler does not.

Why? Because as far as the compiler is concerned, maybe this function *does* try to modify the contents of the string, which would cause your program to crash. Maybe you rely very heavily on this library and there are lots of functions that all behave like this. Then maybe it's easier not to declare the string as `const` in the first place - but then it's all up to you to make sure you don't try to modify it.

On the other hand, if you are the one *writing* the `countLettersInString` function, then simply make sure the compiler knows you won't modify the string by declaring it with `const`:

```
int countLettersInString(char c, char const * str);
```

That way it will accept both constant and non-constant strings without issue.

Answer (score 4):

One disadvantage of using string-literals is that they have length restrictions.
So you should keep in mind from the document ISO/IEC:9899
(emphasis mine)

> 5.2.4.1 Translation limits
>
> 1 The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:
>
> [...]
>
> —  4095 characters in a character string literal or wide string literal (after concatenation)

So If your constant text exceeds this count (What some times throughout may be possible, especially if you write a dynamic webserver in C) you are forbidden to use the string literal approach if you want to stay system independent.

Comment: Eh what ??? The 4095 character constraint is for a SINGLE string-constant. Not for all constants together. And what does this have to do with the question ?

Comment: @Tonny: WHen did I say something different? I mean I cited that it counts for a single character string literal why you are telling it me? But try to build up a complex dynamic HTML page containing 2 or 3 constant parts that will concatenated int to one HTML file. I can Bet you dont get far by respecting this limit! and in how it is related to the question? Well he asked what are the disadvantages compared to malloc. and one of them is that if you can't respect this limit (what is in some work spaces likely) you cant stay system independent using the literal concept over malloc'ing. thats it.

Comment: Now I understand your intent and you make a good point. But that wasn't so clear from your answer by itself. (I was more focusing on the syntactical problems in the code in stead of size limitations). And if I didn't "get" it, there will be a lot of other people too who missed it.

Comment: @Tonny: Would you explain me how this missunderstanding can arise, so I can edit it out? As For me it sounds pretty clear, and I don't know what I should change to prevent this.

Comment: I would add 1 line at the top: "One disadvantage of using const strings is that they have length restrictions".  I still fail to see however how this makes much a difference in practice: If you need very long strings you must dynamically allocate them, but you still need to fill these strings with content from somewhere. Which by definition can't be another const string in the source. You'll loading them dynamically from a file or another resource.

Comment: @Tonny thanks I'll add that. And well, in how far this is conflicting with what I said? Maybe I did a heavy wording error, what you wrote is exactly what I want to express. I'm neither for using dynamic memory nor I'm for generally string literals(Because both ahve situational pros and cons).  I just wanted to throw in the limitation as no one before metnioned it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem in your code as long as you are not planing to modify the contents of that string. Also, the memory for such string literals will remain for the full life time of the program. The memory allocated by `malloc` is **read-write**, so you can manipulate the contents of that memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string literal that you do not want to modify, what you are doing  is ok:

```
char *str = NULL;
str = "This is a test";
str = "Now I am pointing here";
```

Here `str` a pointer has a memory which it points to. In second line you write to that memory `"This is a test"` and then again in 3 line you write in that memory `"Now I am pointing here"`. This is legal in C.

You may find it a bit contradicting but you can't modify string that is something like this -

```
str[0]='X' // will give a problem.
```

However, if you want to be able to modify it, use it as a buffer to hold a line of input and so on, use `malloc`:

```
char *str=malloc(BUFSIZE);   // BUFSIZE size what you want to allocate
free(str);                   // freeing memory
```

Use `malloc()` when you don't know the amount of memory needed during compile time.

Comment: If you really, really must use malloc() make sure you validate the return value (malloc returns NULL on error) and the status of errno.

Comment: @Andrew Why do you recommend checking for `malloc()` errors?

Comment: If malloc() fails, it returns NULL - and you have no memory allocated.  Not checking the return status is one of the biggest reasons why dynamic memory allocation is a Bad Idea!

Comment: @Andrew What are your options when dynamic memory allocation fails? Exit your application with `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`? It's just something I can't imagine happening. Have you ever encountered a failed `malloc`?

Comment: @mucaho - malloc() and any other dynamic memory allocation can and does fail... as for your options - you should always check pointers for NULL and take appropriate action... what that is will depend on your design. Exiting a program is a "if all else fails" action, and rather unsuitable for embedded applications!

Answer (score 1):

It is legal in C *unfortunately*, but any attempt to modify the string literal via the pointer will result in *undefined* behavior.

Say

```
str[0] = 'Y'; //No compiler error, undefined behavior
```

Answer (score 1):

It will run fine, but you may get a warning by the compiler, because you are pointing to a constant string.

P.S.: It will run OK only when you are not modifying it. So the only disadvantage of not using `malloc` is that you won't be able to modify it.